# Find the mixed strategy Nash equilibria in the investment race

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

This is Exercise 35.2 in Rubinstein's "A Course in Game Theory". This problem is very difficult. The lecturer gave us the answer but it's very hard to understand.

I paste the problem here:

Two investors are involved in a competition with a prize of $1$. Each investor can spend any amount in the interval $[0,1]$. The winner is the investor who spends the most; in the event of a tie each investor receives $0.50$. Formulate this situation as a strategic game and find its mixed strategy Nash equilibria.

The payoff function of player $i$ is 
$$u_i(b_1,b_2)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-b_i &  b_i < b_j\\ 
0.5-b_i & b_i = b_j\\ 
1-b_i & b_i > b_j
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I can understand it's mixed Nash equilibrium if both players's probability distribution are uniform on $[0,1]$. But I don't know how this mixed Nash equilibrium is unique.

Comment: To argue that it is unique, try showing that if one player plays any other distribution over [0,1], then the other player has a unique best response (i.e. will not be willing to mix).

Comment: @Shane It seems to me that given player i's distribution function, player j has to find the best distribution function for him among all the possible distributions on [0,1]. This problem is so complicated and I was wondering what mathematical tools to use.